# Regex with 3 substrings

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex to match the following strings:

```
node-primary-backup-2017-08-10-15
node-secondary-backup-2017-06-12-32
node-secondary-backup-2017-08-11-24
node-primary-backup-2017-07-13-02
...
```

I tried the following, but it's not working:

```
node-(?=primary|secondary)-backup-\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just remove `?=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `(?=primary|secondary)` is a *look ahead*, which asserts that the characters immediately following the current position match the specified expression, but it does not consume any input.

Your expression requires that `-backup-\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+` matches `(primary|secondary)`, which of course is impossible.

Just remove `?=` to make it a simple alternation expression:

```
node-(primary|secondary)-backup-\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+
```